# Is there a standard way to list names of Python modules in a package?

Tags: python, module, package

Is there a straightforward way to list the names of all modules in a package, without using `__all__`?

For example, given this package:

```
/testpkg
/testpkg/__init__.py
/testpkg/modulea.py
/testpkg/moduleb.py
```

I'm wondering if there is a standard or built-in way to do something like this:

```
>>> package_contents("testpkg")
['modulea', 'moduleb']
```

The manual approach would be to iterate through the module search paths in order to find the package's directory.  One could then list all the files in that directory, filter out the uniquely-named py/pyc/pyo files, strip the extensions, and return that list.  But this seems like a fair amount of work for something the module import mechanism is already doing internally.  Is that functionality exposed anywhere?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Maybe this will do what you're looking for?

```
import imp
import os
MODULE_EXTENSIONS = ('.py', '.pyc', '.pyo')

def package_contents(package_name):
    file, pathname, description = imp.find_module(package_name)
    if file:
        raise ImportError('Not a package: %r', package_name)
    # Use a set because some may be both source and compiled.
    return set([os.path.splitext(module)[0]
        for module in os.listdir(pathname)
        if module.endswith(MODULE_EXTENSIONS)])
```

Comment: I would add 'and module != "__init__.py"' to the final 'if', since __init__.py isn't really part of the package.  And .pyo is another valid extension.  Aside from that, using imp.find_module is a really good idea; I think this is the right answer.

Comment: I disagree -- you can import __init__ directly, so why special case it? It sure isn't special enough to break the rules. ;-)

Comment: You should probably use `imp.get_suffixes()` instead of your hand-written list.

Comment: Also, note that this doesn't work on subpackages like `xml.sax`

Comment: What is the purpose of `[os.path.splitext(module)[0]`? First of all, module is not defined... do you mean 'package_name' or 'pathname' (which near as I can tell, are always the same), and then why strip the extension from a package name? Would there ever be one? And for that matter, why include the package at all?

Comment: @erich2k8 1) module is defined in the list comprehension, 2) they are stripping the extension from the module name because this method returns the names of modules inside the given package

Comment: This is a really bad way.  You can't reliably tell what's a module from the filename extension.

Comment: Wouldn't work in Jython too if the Jython module is a bunch of compiled `.py$class` files in a .jar file

Comment: This technique will only work for simple packages structured on the filesystem. It won't work for eggs, zip wheels, or packages where modules are loaded dynamically.

Answer (score 243):

Using [python2.3 and above](http://docs.python.org/library/pkgutil.html), you could also use the `pkgutil` module:

```
>>> import pkgutil
>>> [name for _, name, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules(['testpkg'])]
['modulea', 'moduleb']
```

**EDIT:** Note that the parameter for `pkgutil.iter_modules` is not a list of modules, but a list of paths, so you might want to do something like this:

```
>>> import os.path, pkgutil
>>> import testpkg
>>> pkgpath = os.path.dirname(testpkg.__file__)
>>> print([name for _, name, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules([pkgpath])])
```

Comment: This is disturbingly undocumented, but seems like the most correct way to do this. Hope you don't mind I added the note.

Comment: `pkgutil` is there in [python2.3 and up actually](http://docs.python.org/library/pkgutil.html). Also, while `pkgutil.iter_modules()` will not work recursively, there is a `pkgutil.walk_packages()` as well, which _will_ recurse. Thanks for the pointer to this package though.

Comment: Why `iter_modules` doesn't work for absolute import like `a.b.testpkg`? It is giving me `[]`

Comment: Taking the OP literally, I don't see why you would need to use `os.path.dirname`, but then again, I think it will work with or without it because testpkg is a directory.

Comment: I can't confirm that `pkgutil.walk_packages()` recurses, it gives me the same output as `pkgutil.iter_modules()`, so I think the answer is incomplete.

Comment: This method fails to find `os.path` as a submodule of `os`.  But maybe this is a special case?

Comment: If anyone cares, this also works perfectly in python 3.8 (Just saying as original post is quiet old)

Comment: I don't think you need to use os at all here. You should be able to just do: `[name for _, name, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules(testpkg.__path__)]`

Comment: @kbuilds @AlanSE, you need `dirname` because `pkg.__file__` points to `__init__.py` file

Comment: what if my package name is `Office365-REST-Python-Client`

Comment: @sjd That's impossible, because Python package names can't have dashes in them. (**Distribution** package names at e.g. pypi.org can use dashes in the name, but when that's installed the package name is something else.) For your example, `pip install Office365-REST-Python-Client` installs a python package named `office365`, with subpackages like `office365.sharepoint` and `office365.runtime`. (Possibly others, I'm just going by their README's example code.)

Answer (score 55):

```
import module
help(module)
```

Comment: Although help does list package contents at the bottom of the help text, the question is more along the lines of how to do this: f(package_name) => ["module1_name", "module2_name"].  I suppose I could parse the string returned by help, but that seems more roundabout than listing the directory.

Comment: @DNS: `help()` prints stuff, it doesn't return a string.

Comment: I agree this is a roundabout way but it sent me down a rabbit hole to see how `help()` works. Anyway, the built-in `pydoc` module can help spit out the string that `help()` paginates: `import pydoc; pydoc.render_doc('mypackage')`.

Answer (score 18):

<strike>Don't know if I'm overlooking something, or if the answers are just out-dated but;</strike>

As stated by user815423426 this only works for live objects and the listed modules are only modules that were imported before.

Listing modules in a package seems really easy using [inspect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html):

```
>>> import inspect, testpkg
>>> inspect.getmembers(testpkg, inspect.ismodule)
['modulea', 'moduleb']
```

Comment: I've put  imported = __import__('myproj.mymod.mysubmod') m = inspect.getmembers(i, inspect.ismodule) but importd path is ~/myproj/__init__.py and m is a list with (mymod, '~/myproj/mymod/__init__.py')

Comment: @hithwen Don't ask questions in the comments, especially if they're not directly related. Being a good Samaritan: Use `imported = import importlib; importlib.import_module('myproj.mymod.mysubmod')`. `__import__` imports the top-level module, [see the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__).

Comment: Hmm, this is promising but it's  not working for me. When I do `import inspect, mypackage` and then `inspect.getmembers(my_package, inspect.ismodule)` I get an empty list, even though I certainly have various modules in it.

Comment: As a matter of fact, this only seems to work if I `import my_package.foo` and not just `import mypackage`, in which case it then returns `foo`. But this defeats the purpose

Comment: By the way, if you read the documentation of `inspect`, it explicitly says it is a library to inspect **live objects**, which is why it doesn't show anything that has not been loaded yet.

Comment: @user815423426 You are absolutely right ;-) Seems like I was overlooking something.

Answer (score 4):

This is a recursive version that works with python 3.6 and above:

```
import importlib.util
from pathlib import Path
import os
MODULE_EXTENSIONS = '.py'

def package_contents(package_name):
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec(package_name)
    if spec is None:
        return set()

    pathname = Path(spec.origin).parent
    ret = set()
    with os.scandir(pathname) as entries:
        for entry in entries:
            if entry.name.startswith('__'):
                continue
            current = '.'.join((package_name, entry.name.partition('.')[0]))
            if entry.is_file():
                if entry.name.endswith(MODULE_EXTENSIONS):
                    ret.add(current)
            elif entry.is_dir():
                ret.add(current)
                ret |= package_contents(current)


    return ret
```

Comment: What's the advantage of using `os.scandir` as a context manager instead of iterating over the result entries directly?

Comment: @monkut See https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir which suggest using it as a context manager to ensure that `close` is called when you are done with it to ensure that any held resources are released.

Comment: this doesnt work for `re` instead it lists every package but adds `re.` to all of them

Answer (score 3):

This should list the modules:

```
help("modules")
```

Comment: This is not an answer. It prints all available modules, while author asks for modules in a given package.

Answer (score 3):

There is a `__loader__` variable inside each package instance. So, if you import the package, you can find the "module resources" inside the package:

```py
import testpkg # change this by your package name

for mod in testpkg.__loader__.get_resource_reader().contents():
    print(mod)
```

You can of course improve the loop to find the "module" name:

```py
import testpkg

from pathlib import Path

for mod in testpkg.__loader__.get_resource_reader().contents():
    # You can filter the name like 
    # Path(l).suffix not in (".py", ".pyc")
    print(Path(mod).stem)
```

Inside the package, you can find your modules by directly using `__loader__` of course.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to view an inforamtion about your package outside of the python code (from a command prompt) you can use pydoc for it.

```
# get a full list of packages that you have installed on you machine
$ python -m pydoc modules

# get information about a specific package
$ python -m pydoc <your package>
```

You will have the same result as pydoc but inside of interpreter using help

```
>>> import <my package>
>>> help(<my package>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on cdleary's example, here's a recursive version listing path for all submodules:

```
import imp, os

def iter_submodules(package):
    file, pathname, description = imp.find_module(package)
    for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(pathname):
        for  filename in filenames:
            if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] == ".py":
                yield os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here will run the code in the package as they inspect it. If  you don't want that, you can grep the files like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26836201/a-smarter-grep-for-python-code-want-to-find-nesting-function-or-class)

```py
def _get_class_names(file_name: str) -> List[str]:
    """Get the python class name defined in a file without running code
    file_name: the name of the file to search for class definitions in
    return: all the classes defined in that python file, empty list if no matches"""
    defined_class_names = []
    # search the file for class definitions
    with open(file_name, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            # regular expression for class defined in the file
            # searches for text that starts with "class" and ends with ( or :,
            # whichever comes first
            match = re.search("^class(.+?)(\(|:)", line) # noqa
            if match:
                # add the cleaned match to the list if there is one
                defined_class_name = match.group(1).strip()
                defined_class_names.append(defined_class_name)
    return defined_class_names
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete @Metal3d answer, yes you can do `testpkg.__loader__.get_resource_reader().contents()` to list the "module resources" but it will work only if you imported your package in the "normal" way and your loader is `_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object`.

But if you imported your library with `zipimport` (ex: to load your package in memory), your loader will be a `zipimporter object`, and its `get_resource_reader` function is different from importlib; it will require a "fullname" argument.

To make it work in these two loaders, just specify your package name in argument to `get_resource_reader` :

```py
# An example with CrackMapExec tool

import importlib

import cme.protocols as cme_protocols


class ProtocolLoader:
    def get_protocols(self):
        protocols = {}
        protocols_names = [x for x in cme_protocols.__loader__.get_resource_reader("cme.protocols").contents()]

        for prot_name in protocols_names:
            prot = importlib.import_module(f"cme.protocols.{prot_name}")
            protocols[prot_name] = prot

        return protocols
```

Answer (score -3):

```
def package_contents(package_name):
  package = __import__(package_name)
  return [module_name for module_name in dir(package) if not module_name.startswith("__")]
```

Comment: That only works for modules, not packages.  Try it on Python's `logging` package to see what I mean.  Logging contains two modules: handlers and config.  Your code will return a list of 66 items, which doesn't include those two names.