# whatprovides equivalent for pip or easy_install

Tags: pip, easy-install, yum

In yum we can do a `yum whatprovides *filename`. Is there any such equivalent in pip or easy_install?

If I am getting an error in importing py module fooblabla,  how can I find out which python egg/package provides that?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try?

```
$ pip search <packagename>
```

This query searches the package metadata (including name, short description, keywords, among others).
It doesn't seem quite as deep a search as the `whatprovides` functionality, but unless you have the package installed already, it isn't clear how you would find the modules contained within that package (see [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487971/is-there-a-standard-way-to-list-names-of-python-modules-in-a-package) for that case).

However, I also don't see how you wouldn't know the package name if you were having problems importing a module from it.