# A smarter 'grep' for python code: want to find nesting function or class

Tags: python, grep, full-text-search

I am searching a python script for a string, but I would like to see not just the lines that contain the string, but also if that code is nested inside a function or method (or, optionally, a loop or conditional), I would like to see the lines where that function/method/etc. is 'declared' (not sure if that's the right terminology...)

I just mean, when I'm looking for STRING in a file like this:

```
class my_class(stuff):
     some lines of code
     line of code containing STRING
```

I'd like it to return:

```
class my_class(stuff):
     line of code containing STRING
```

Instead of just:

```
     line of code containing STRING
```

It doesn't have to be done with grep, specifically.

Answer (score 2):

Nice answer from nullpointer, but a slight modification to limit this to just class or function definitions (rather than including if/lambda/etc) and only using grep...

```
grep -rE "^\s*def.*:$|STRING" some-directory/ | grep "STRING" -B 1
```

or

```
grep -rE "^\s*class.*:$|STRING" some-directory/ | grep "STRING" -B 1
```

This works for my purposes, but you can modify the `-B` argument to suit your needs if you're dealing with nested things or if STRING repeats in a given fn/class. The second grep basically ensures STRING is present and that the last match from the first grep is shown, which could be STRING again... in that case you might adjust -B.

Answer (score 0):

**Using grep**

```
$ grep -E ':$|STRING' input
    class my_class(stuff):
         line of code containing STRING
```

**What it does**

- `/:$|STRING/` regex matches `:` at the end of line `$` as in `class` `def` or any control structure in python. or `STRING`

This solution will list the class or control structure name followed by the strings which match the `STRING` that may contain inside them. If the are not contained, the class defenition would be printed. A small tweak on `awk` will print all the function/ class header with the string only if they are present

**print class and string only if the `STRING` is present**

```
$ awk '/:$/{header=$0} /STRING/{print header; print $0}' input
class my_class(stuff):
     line of code containing STRING
```

**What it does**

- `/:$/{header=$0}` if line matches the regex `:$`, assign the class/function header to `header` varialbe.
- `/STRING/{print header; print $0}` if line matches `STRING` print the `header` followed by the entire record, `$0`